# HtmlDataTable Not Serializable

Tags: jsf-1.2, session-replication

I am trying to Session repication in cluster envoirnment. After change all my backing beans to serialized object but I am unable to Serialize HtmlDataTable

`Caused By: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1401)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:332)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionChange.writeExternal(ReplicatedSessionChange.java:124)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1399)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:332)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevOutputStream.writeObject(MsgAbbrevOutputStream.java:618)
    at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevOutputStream.writeObjectWL(MsgAbbrevOutputStream.java:609)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.writeObject(ObjectIO.java:38)
    at weblogic.rjvm.BasicOutboundRequest.marshalArgs(BasicOutboundRequest.java:88)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:221)
    at weblogic.cluster.replication.ReplicationManager_1033_WLStub.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler$ReplicationServicesInvocationAction.run(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:184)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.cluster.replication.SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.invoke(SecureReplicationInvocationHandler.java:154)
    at $Proxy58.update(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.cluster.replication.ReplicationManager.updateSecondary(ReplicationManager.java:532)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionData.syncSession(ReplicatedSessionData.java:594)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.ReplicatedSessionContext.sync(ReplicatedSessionContext.java:85)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2810)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl$SessionHelper.syncSession(ServletRequestImpl.java:2785)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl$1.run(ServletResponseImpl.java:1480)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.send(ServletResponseImpl.java:1474)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1455)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)`

Please help....

Comment: I have already adeded the below Bean.java <code>private transient HtmlDataTable dataTable = new HtmlDataTable(); </code> Web.xml <code><context-param>
<param-name>
org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION
</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param></code>